Confirming the Legitimacy of a Job Offer
A couple of weeks ago, I got a LinkedIn message from someone with a detailed work history but no profile picture, inviting me to interview for a remote role at a company in Greece. They mentioned that we might set up a meeting where one of us would travel to meet the team.
Recently, I was told that the person will be coming to my country and suggested we meet at their hotel, which is in a different city. While it's a major city and not unexpected, the whole situation feels a bit unusual to me.
I’m a bit concerned about whether this is legitimate, especially since there’s not much information online about the company. Their website has some details but features generic customer photos, and I couldn’t find any specific matches for those names.
Can you advise on how I might verify if the company is real and how best to move forward?

Did you already speak before, outside linkedin chat? A video call is almost always a good start.

@SouravGhosh We had a quick voice call on WhatsApp.

@JoeStrazzere Yes exactly. We had a quick, non-technical call on WhatsApp, and he told me that he sensed good qualities that could be useful for the position, and he told me that it might be beneficial to set an in-person meeting to get to know each other and the team more.

Sounds like a scam. An individual who doesn’t have a profile, has a job for you, let me guess it takes money or personal documents to move to the next step…

Is there a reason that this company knew of you?
It isn't likely that a company would directly reachout. Recruiters will reach out to people randomly. No so much companies.
There are too many ways that this can be a scam, "Generic Photos" and "one of us would travel" are red flags.
Don't give out any personal info, money, etc. if you do choose to move forward.
Consider being safe and ignoring them.

The more I search for the company online, the more concerned I get. There's absolutely no information about them. Their office address is a commercial building, but I found nothing about them on Google Maps after thorough checking. The only phone number is the CEO's mobile, and the GEMI website has no record of their registration. Is it even worth messaging the CEO for more information at this point?

@ma_jafari Random internet people, like me, can't tell you what to do. But, IMHO this smells very fishy. Or Phishy. It would be much safer to find a job with a verifiable company. Good luck.

Depends on your field.  In good markets I would get daily reachouts by big tech firms as a programmer.  It's still not uncommon in today's market-  I got a random reachout from PayPal yesterday.  If you have a linkedin account or a public facing resume with contact info, a company's internal HR team will reach out to you.  That said, a few other things about this do seem like yellow flags.

@GabeSechan Agreed on everything you said. OP didn't say any of the positives, only the signs of phishing.

@ma_jafari - Actual companies are registered and have phone numbers not the CEO mobile number and a generic office building (likely a virtual office). It’s a scam

My golden rule on LinkedIn is if they have no profile picture, I am not interested.  I don't add them to my circle, I don't respond to their messages.
As far as I am concerned, they have something to hide.  Also look at their profile, the timeline of their education often tells you its fake.
Finally, if they don't have many connections already, then there is a good chance they may be fake.  How desperate are to enlarge your circle?  I am not.
